# How to get (with a fixed range and offset) linearly proportional signal from a variable range on the input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain, signal-integrity, inverting-amplifier

**Ask:** How to get (with a fixed range and offset) linearly proportional signal from a variable range on the input?

**Conditions:** There's a signal (to simplify, consider a sinusoid) with variable amplitude (min. 165mV to max. 1.65V) and variable offset so that the signal's lower value is above and close to 0.

I need a circuit to catch the signal no matter what amplitude and then get an output linearly proportional signal that goes from 0 to 3.3v, as shown bellow:

[image]

An AmpOp may be used in association with a digital potentiometer, to vary digitally it's gain. In this configuration, for the max. amplitude, gain should be 1. For the lower amplitude, the gain should be around 10.

P.S.: Said that, the actual signal is a trapezoidal signal that comes from a DC brushless motor phase, like bellow:

[image]

[EDIT - A test with a possibly solution]
Using the following circuit, it was possible to obtain a signal from the variable amplitude input signal:
[image]
Setting the input signal to a sinusoidal 0-to-6v, and the 50k potentiometer to 91%, we have both graphs bellow:
[image]
[image]
Setting the input signal to a sinusoidal 0-to-60v, and the 50k potentiometer to 51%, we have both graphs bellow:
[image]
[image]

Both situations were simulated to 1.0kHz signal on the input. I would like to know if you guys have any advice or any real question which simulation doesn't take into account. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need an AGC (automatic gain control) or some servo feedback.

Comment: @winny, I was thinking how to solve this using a digital potentiometer associated with an AmpOp. The goal is to catch the output voltage with an ADC.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you need a variable gain amplifier - are you saying that when the signal is only 165 mV, that you want it to become 1.65 volts and, when the signal is 1.65 volts you want to leave it unchanged AND, in both cases, you want the output signal to be centred so that its lower level doesn't go negative? Thing is this; if you are interested in the amplitude of the signal then that information is lost by the variable gain amplifier so, please explain what the point is of your requirement.

Comment: Sure, I'll clarify remaking the text.

Comment: @Andyaka, I need to transform linearly a input signal into a fixed amplitude output signal, so that the level doesn't  goes bellow zero voltage.

Comment: @EmanuelM OK, so what are you trying to determine from the "reformed" signal. After all, you've lost amplitude information due to the automatic gain control. I'm asking this because it might be relevant and I can't see a reason why you want to lose amplitude variation information.

Comment: @Andyaka, It is to be read by the microcontroller's ADC. This will give more accuracy compared, while minimum signal on entry will be enlarged to a 0-to-3.3 range.

Comment: If the signal looks the same then want can reading it by an ADC tell you? Think about it.

Comment: @Andyaka, the amplitude does not give me anything useful. I expect a trapezoidal wave at the output, it's frequency is the important parameter. To get this information, I need to "normalize" into a 0-to-3.3v range wave and then capture it with the ADC.

Comment: You don't need to normalize the waveform to get its frequency. Beginning to sound like an XY problem to me - you think you need to analogue process a signal but you don't. There are better ways.

Comment: @Andyaka, I need to realize the moment the trapezoidal input signal crosses it's own mid point. That's a way to measure the speed of a brushless motor and then act to commutate the coils. But that's only one method. I am developing a board to drive a brushless motor, so that I can manage to use different methods to threat the signal, that's why I need a analogue process stage.

Comment: You don't need to amplitude stabilize the waveform to do this and you don't need an ADC.

Comment: Assuming I'm trying to use different methods, I do need to stabilize the waveform because comparing 6v to 60v input signal max, I would lose more than 3 bit on my ADC ( 6v/60v = 10x less range > 2^3 off the ADC bits).

Answer (score 2):

If the sine wave is truly representative, simply AC-couple and re-bias to 1.65 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX0LkN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You got the point: How to re-bias?

Comment: @EmanuelM, what power sources do you have available?

Comment: I'm planning on using let's say +3.3 DC voltage, with no negative voltages. The actual signal is a trapezoidal wave that comes from any of the 3 brushless DC motor phase, like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Osama_Arafa2/publication/278303636/figure/fig3/AS:294339797372932@1447187484318/Non-Ideal-Trapezoidal-Waveform-conduction-period-per-phase-per-half-cycle110.png)

Comment: Is the signal balanced? Meaning is the mean value of the signal equal to the midpoint between the maximum and minimum voltages? If not, you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: It is perfectly symmetric.

Comment: @EmanuelM, Ok then this answer should still work.

Comment: I've updated (at the description) a version of a circuit that could solve it, thanks to your clue. Do you think it is a reliable implementation, considering the application of real components, and then, it will be able to have a good accuracy for the ADC to get the input signal?